# Php Archives (Phar) do not uncompress text files

Tags: php, apache, phar

I am deploying my Php application as a compressed Php Archive (Phar), I have noticed that when using gzip compression the css and other text files are not uncompressed and look like gibberish. When disabling compression they are fine.

I am using the default stub which sets the mime type for css files. Is there some setting I must enable in order for the Phar to uncompress non-php files? Or is the Phar working as intended and I need to echo out the contents of text files from within a Php script?

Comment: You should maybe include the file you are using to create the phar. It may give clues about why everything is compressed.